# how to execute trigger when only one column changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following trigger, and I  need that its only executed when one column value changes, is that possible?

```
  ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_HISTORICO]
    ON [dbo].[Tbl_Contactos]
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS
     BEGIN
   IF UPDATE (primerNombre) -- sólo si actualiza PRIMER NOMBRE
   BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tbl_Historico] ([fecha],[idUsuario],[valorNuevo], [idContacto],[tipoHistorico] )
    SELECT  getdate(), 1, [dbo].[Encrypt]([dbo].[Decrypt](primerNombre)), [idContacto], 1
    FROM INSERTED        
   END  

   END
```

The problem is the code is executed always even if another column changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably the way you are doing updates in your code. It may be updating every field and not only the one that changed.

In this case you need to check to see if there is a difference between the values in the inserted and deleted pseudo tables. Or fix your code so that it only updates what needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the value of `primerNombre` from the `inserted` and `deleted` tables

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_HISTORICO] ON [dbo].[Tbl_Contactos]
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tbl_Historico] ([fecha],[idUsuario],[valorNuevo], [idContacto],[tipoHistorico] )
SELECT getdate(), 1, [dbo].[Encrypt]([dbo].[Decrypt](i.primerNombre)), i.[idContacto], 1
FROM INSERTED i
 inner join deleted d 
   on i.idContacto = d.idContacto
where i.primerNombre <> d.primerNombre  
END
```

If `primerNombre` is nullable, the `where` will need to handle `null` comparisons as well.